# Extract the date from a column also with a text

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a problem. I want to extract the date the format is `dd.MM.YYYY` or `dd.MM.YY` from a column. The problem is that the column contains some *words* e.g. `ETA`, `ETA:`, `ETA: Something`. How could I extract the dates of the columns, also when the first words are `ETA` or `ETA:`

Table

```
ETA: 12.05.23
12.05.23
ETA Something
ETA 12.05.2024
ETA Something agian
```

Formula

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(DATEVALUE(MID(J35, FIND("ETA: ", J35) + 5, 10))), DATEVALUE(MID(J35, FIND("ETA: ", J35) + 5, 10)), "-")
```

What I got

```
ETA: 12.05.23             -
12.05.23                  -
ETA Something             -
ETA 12.05.2024            -
ETA Something agian       -
```

---

What I want

```
ETA: 12.05.23             12.05.23
12.05.23                  12.05.23
ETA Something             -
ETA 12.05.2024            12.05.24
ETA Something agian       -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***formula_1***

*this just extracts the date style but not an actual date & will test `FALSE` for [isdate()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9061381)*

```js
=index(ifna(regexextract(A2:A,"\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2,4}")))
```

***formula_2***

*the output is actual date & will test `TRUE` for isdate(). ***one caveat*** is if the year number is available as just 2 digits, I hardcoded it to the current 21st century*

```js
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,to_date(ifna(let(Λ,regexextract(Σ,"(\d{2}).(\d{2}).(\d{2,4})"),Γ,index(Λ,,3),
     date(if(len(Γ)=2,"20"&Γ,Γ),index(Λ,,2),index(Λ,,1))),"--")))))
```

[image]